# Error with Boto and creating my instance

Tags: python, git, amazon-web-services, boto

When I run my code I get this, I'm creating a VPC with two subnets and within 2 instances but within the same subnet. My problem occurs when I try to atach the subnet to the instance I get this error and as you can see on the first screen make the subnet both the name and the ID of each display to assign the ID

```
================================================================
============== creating the VPC ====================================
================================================================
Creating VPC with name: SAS1
================================================================
============== creating the IG ======================================
================================================================
Creating Internet Gateway with name: SAS1
================================================================
============== creating the Route ===================================
================================================================
Creating Route Table with name: public
================================================================
============== creating the subnets =================================
================================================================
Creating Subnet with name: sas01 in: us-west-2a
Subnet created with the name :  sub-sas1   and the ID is :   Subnet:subnet-2e65af4a
Creating Subnet with name: sas02 in: us-west-2a
Subnet created with the name :  sub-sas2   and the ID is :   Subnet:subnet-2f65af4b
Subnet:subnet-2f65af4b
Subnet:subnet-2e65af4a
================================================================
============== creating the hosts ===================================
================================================================
Creating Security Group with name: sas-sg
Creating Instance with name: sas01
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Guille/Documents/git/aws_vpc_py/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/main.py", line 732, in main
    *args, **kwargs
  File "/Users/Guille/Documents/git/aws_vpc_py/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 345, in execute
    results['<local-only>'] = task.run(*args, **new_kwargs)
  File "/Users/Guille/Documents/git/aws_vpc_py/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 121, in run
    return self.wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Guille/Documents/git/aws_vpc_py/fabfile.py", line 25, in make_vpc
    bastion_hosts = aws.make_vpc(vpc_name)
  File "/Users/Guille/Documents/git/aws_vpc_py/aws.py", line 71, in make_vpc
    bastion = get_or_create_bastion_host(conn, vpc_config, bastion_host_name, vpc, Subnet[0])
  File "/Users/Guille/Documents/git/aws_vpc_py/aws.py", line 127, in get_or_create_bastion_host
    key_name=key_pair.name, subnet= Subnet[0])
NameError: global name 'Subnet' is not defined
```

---

this is part of the code that i run:

```
bastion_hosts = [] 
    for instancia in vpc_config.sections():
        if (instancia != 'vpc' ) and (instancia != 'sub-sas1' ) and ( instancia != 'sub-sas2'):
            cidr_block = vpc_config.get(instancia, 'cidr_block')
            bastion_host_name = vpc_config.get(instancia, 'bastion_host')
            instance_type = vpc_config.get(instancia,'default_instance_type')
            availability_zone = vpc_config.get(instancia, 'availability_zone')
            bastion = get_or_create_bastion_host(conn, vpc_config, bastion_host_name, vpc, Subnet[0])
            bastion_hosts.append(bastion)
            print bastion_hosts

    return bastion_hosts
```

where bastion is define by :

```
def get_or_create_bastion_host(conn, vpc_config, bastion_host_name, vpc, subnet):
    image_id = vpc_config.get('vpc', 'default_image_id')
    image_login_user = vpc_config.get('vpc', 'default_image_login_user')
    instance_type = vpc_config.get('vpc','default_instance_type')
    key_pair = get_bastion_host_key(conn, vpc_config)
    security_group = get_or_create_vpc_security_group(conn, vpc_config, vpc.id)

    for reservation in fetch_running_reservations(conn, bastion_host_name, vpc.id):
        for instance in reservation.instances:
            public_ip = associate_elastic_ip(conn, instance)
            return Node(bastion_host_name, public_ip, image_login_user, BASTION_KEY_FILE)

    print 'Creating Instance with name:', bastion_host_name
    reservation = conn.ec2.run_instances(image_id, instance_type=instance_type,
                                         security_group_ids=[security_group.id],
                                         key_name=key_pair.name, subnet= Subnet[0])

    for instance in reservation.instances:
        print 'Waiting for', bastion_host_name, instance.id, 'to start ...'
        wait_until(instance, 'running')
        tag_with_name(instance, bastion_host_name)
        public_ip = associate_elastic_ip(conn, instance)
        print bastion_host_name, 'is associated with Elastic IP', public_ip
        return Node(bastion_host_name, public_ip, image_login_user, BASTION_KEY_FILE)
```

Any help ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use `Subnet[0]` when there is no such variable defined in the scope. Since you are passing `subnet` to `get_or_create_bastion_host`, you should use `subnet` instead of `Subnet[0]`.

get_or_create_bastion_host(conn, vpc_config, bastion_host_name, vpc, **subnet**)

To make it work, try assigning the passed `subnet` to the parameter `subnet`:

```
reservation = conn.ec2.run_instances(image_id, instance_type=instance_type,
                                     security_group_ids=[security_group.id],
                                     key_name=key_pair.name, subnet_id=subnet)
```

Comment: Now i get this error: File "/Users/Guille/Documents/git/aws_vpc_py/aws.py", line 127, in get_or_create_bastion_host
    key_name=key_pair.name, subnet= subnet)
TypeError: run_instances() got an unexpected keyword argument 'subnet' I try to assign the subnet to the instance thou the name of the subnet

Comment: @ZioGuillo I checked the signature of boto `run_instances`, the parameter is `subnet_id`. So try `subnet_id = subnet`

Comment: Now I get this :  <Response><Errors><Error><Code>InvalidSubnetID.NotFound</Code><Message>The subnet ID 'Subnet:subnet-f18a5f95' does not exist</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>ea036ecd-0ac9-4be9-9a53-d3e5dd62c09e</RequestID></Response> because Subnet[0] save the subnet that i want to assign to this instance. So How I can select the subnet id from my external file : [sas01-host]
primary = True
default_instance_type = r3.8xlarge
ssh_hosts = 10.80.0.*
cidr_block = 10.80.0.0/24
subnet = sub-sas1
availability_zone = us-west-2a
bastion_host = sas01

Comment: You have to open the file, read the data in and store the values in a variable and then call your functions.